# WPF Deploying issue

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application which plays music using a windows media element. The code is below to play the music:

```
   public void PlaySound()
    {

        string solutionPath = Directory.GetParent(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).Parent.Parent.Parent.FullName;
        string path = Path.Combine(solutionPath, "FolderNameWithinSolution", myMusic.wav);
        mediaElement.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
        mediaElement.Stop();
        mediaElement.Source = new Uri(path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        mediaElement.Volume = 0.2;
        mediaElement.Play(); 


    }
```

the myMusic.wav is a file held in the FolderNameWithinSolution. This is set as Content & copy Always. It all works fine until I deploy it and then the app just wont play the music.

I checked the Application files and the folder is apprearing with the music within it however the music is showing as myMusic.wav.deploy.

Can someone please assist with where I have set this incorrectly. I have also tried renaming the file in the applcation files to remvoe the .deploy but that still did not work,

Answer (score 0):

`.Parent.Parent.Parent.FullName` means you're probably looking for a .WAV file in the same place as your .SLN file, when you're program is run from the `project\bin\debug` directory. This isn't the place that the .WAV file is after it's deployed. In addition, I believe `Copy Always` should be copying the .WAV file into the same directory that you're executable is in. Since you're locating the sound file using your executable as the starting point in the navigation, you need to make sure it's located in the exact same place relative to the executable both in the development environment and after deployment.

Basically, your file is moving to somewhere else when you deploy. Make sure you specify where it's supposed to go in both your build configuration and in your installer configuration.